# php regexp Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier ']'

Tags: php, regex

```
        $p5p6patterns = array(
            "/(\d{2,3}(?:[\.,]\d)?)[\\\\/](\d{2,2}(?:[\.,]\d)?)\D/ui", //62.2/43.2  43/34 34\23
            "/(\d{2,3}(?:[\.,] ?\d)?)[\\\\/](\d{2,2}(?:[\.,] ?\d)?)\D/ui", // 51, 2/30, 5/11, 8
            "/\D(\d{2,3}(?:[\.,]\d)?) ?[\\\\/] ?(\d{2,2}(?:[\.,]\d)?)\D/ui", //62.2 / 43.2 / 7.4
            "/Общая\sплощадь\s\-\s(\d{1,2}(?:[\.,]?\d)?)\sкв\.м\.\sжилая\s\-\s(\d{1,2}(?:[\.,]?\d)?)\sкв\.м\./ui"// Общая площадь - 74.6 кв.м. жилая - 29.8 кв.м.
        );
```

> Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier ']'

Comment: \\\\/] too much escaping

Comment: @migg: Or not enough escaping.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Yes... we'll never know ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

test this put `\\\\\/]` instead of `\\\\/]`

```
$p5p6patterns = array(
        "/(\d{2,3}(?:[\.,]\d)?)[\\\\\/](\d{2,2}(?:[\.,]\d)?)\D/ui", //62.2/43.2  43/34 34\23
        "/(\d{2,3}(?:[\.,] ?\d)?)[\\\\\/](\d{2,2}(?:[\.,] ?\d)?)\D/ui", // 51, 2/30, 5/11, 8
        "/\D(\d{2,3}(?:[\.,]\d)?) ?[\\\\\/] ?(\d{2,2}(?:[\.,]\d)?)\D/ui", //62.2 / 43.2 / 7.4
        "/Общая\sплощадь\s\-\s(\d{1,2}(?:[\.,]?\d)?)\sкв\.м\.\sжилая\s\-\s(\d{1,2}(?:[\.,]?\d)?)\sкв\.м\./ui"// Общая площадь - 74.6 кв.м. жилая - 29.8 кв.м.
    );
```

`preg_match_all()` didnt give  pattern as array

```
int preg_match_all ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = PREG_PATTERN_ORDER [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this part: `[\\\\/]`

`\\\\` encodes a single literal backslash. Therefore, the following `/` is not escaped, ending the regex - and telling the regex compiler to interpret `]` as a mode modifier.

Either use `[\\\\\/]` if you want to match both backslashes and slashes, or `\/` if you just want to match slashes.